# Pick out a parameter from ng-repeat and repeat the selected properties

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to display the json in a certain format with ng-repeat, but have had no success. 
This is the structure:

```
  <div ng-repeat="book in books">
      {{book}}
      <div ng-repeat="name in book.name" >{{name}} </div>
 </div>
```

THis is the structure how I want it to display on the page:

```
 Genre: 
 Sci-fic
    Bookname1
    Bookname2
 Non sci-fic
    Bookname3
    Bookname4
```

This is the json sample:

```
 [{"Genre":Sci-fic,"Name":"Bookname1"},
 {"Genre":Sci-fic,"Name":"Bookname2"},
 {"Genre":Non sci-fic,"Name":"Bookname3"},    
 {"Genre":Non sci-fic,"Name":"Bookname4"}]
```

Comment: How does your JSON look ?

Comment: So, the book is really a genre? And the name is a book? Change names on more meaningful.

Comment: @OmriAharon I just updated question with the json sample

Comment: @zishe: I changed the name, so you could assume that it's a list of books where there are different genres and each book will let you know its genre and the name of it.

Comment: For first element, what `book.name` is? I cannot see how it could be an array.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/4053/

Should/Need to fix/restructure your JSON

```
$scope.books = [
        {
            "genre": "Sci-fic",
            "titles" : ['Bookname1', 'Bookname2']
        },
        {
            "genre": "Non sci-fic",
            "titles" : ['Bookname3', 'Bookname4']
        },
    ];

 <div ng-repeat="book in books">
      {{book.genre}}
      <div ng-repeat="title in book.titles" >{{title}}</div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't it be easier if you format the json object that you receive like this?:

```
[{
    "name": "Sci-Fic", 
    "names":["book 1","book 2"]
    },
    {
    "name": "Another Genre", 
    "names":["book 1","book 2"]
    }
  ]
```

Why don't u use ul and li? just another approach.

```
<ul>
   <li ng-repeat="genre in books">
      {{genre.name}}
       <ul>
         <li ng-repeat="name in genre.names">{{name}}</li>
       </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Hope it helps :D

---Edit---
Sry, didn't see @Christopher Marshall answer while i was writing, its the same thing.

Comment: This way doesn't quite work especially when books is a data model being fed in for some reason. The elements contain it are commented out when I debug them, so basically the data isn't bind at all

Answer (score 0):

If the data MUST be in that format you can do this:

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="ParentCtrl">
        <div data-ng-repeat="genre in data | orderBy:'Genre'">
            <span data-ng-if="(data | orderBy:'Genre')[$index - 1].Genre != genre.Genre">
            {{ genre.Genre }}
            </span>
            <div style="padding-left: 30px;">{{ genre.Name }}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's a jsFiddle of it: http://jsfiddle.net/wgLnH/